# How to remove indexing brackets when making functions return multiple objects?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to use functions to cut down on lines of code, but my output isn't as clean as I'd like. Specifically, when returning multiple elements from a function (by making a list and using `return`), R also prints what I think are indexing numbers (ex. `[[1]][[1]][[1]]`). To make my markdown document cleaner and more readable, I'd like to remove those little numbers.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Looking around SO didn't really lead me anywhere. cat() doesn't work here since I'm trying to return a plot and a table.

An example using the iris dataset (with ggplot2, dplyr, and kableExtra packages):

```
data(iris)

TypeLoop <- function(fun) {
  all <- fun(c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"),"All")
  set <- fun("setosa","Setosa")
  vers <- fun("versicolor","Versicolor")
  virg <- fun("virginica","Verginica")
  out <- list(all,set,vers,virg)
  return(out)
}

PlotNTable <- function(type,name) {
  myplot <- ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_histogram(data=filter(iris, Species %in% type),color="white",fill="darkblue") +
    labs(x="Sepal Length", y="Frequency",
         title=paste(name,": Sepal Length"))

  sep.table <- iris %>%
    filter(Species %in% type) %>%
    group_by(Sepal.Length) %>%
    summarize("Less than 6" = sum(Sepal.Length<6),
                "6 to 7" = sum(Sepal.Length<7 & Sepal.Length>=6),
                "More than 7" = sum(Sepal.Length>7))
  mytable <- kable(sep.table, caption = paste(name,": Sepal Length")) %>%
    kable_styling(c("striped","bordered","hover")) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = T) 

  #Make the function return both objects
  out <- list(myplot,mytable)
  return(out)
}

#Return the plots and tables
TypeLoop(PlotNTable)
```

I include the `results='asis'` option in the top of the code chunk to make it actually knit the markdown document.

Also, I'm fairly new to R, so if you see red flags/redundancies/better ways to do things I try to do in this code, please let me know!

Comment: did you try unlist()  ?

Comment: I just tried adding `out <- list(myplot,mytable)
  vec_out <- unlist(out)
  return(vec_out)` to the end of my code, but it just returned a ridiculously long list of items like `[[1]][[1]]$data.Sepal.Length1[1] 5.1`. I'm guessing it's because unlist turns the list into a vector, which doesn't really jive with plots and other more complicated outputs?

Comment: So you want to print other stuff in the console like `<td style="text-align:right;font-weight: bold;"> 7.7 </td>`....but remove only those index numbers  (`[[4]][[2]]`) ?

Comment: @RonakShah when I use `results='asis'` at the top of the code, it prints a nicely formatted table (thanks to the kableExtra package). So yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, I think this will give the effect you want. Use `flatten()` to remove the list hierarchy, and `walk()` to iterate and print the results for their side-effects only.

```r
library(purrr)

#Return the plots and tables
x <- TypeLoop(PlotNTable)

walk(flatten(x), print)
```

Comment: hmm. this code didn't work for me - might it be because `flatten` makes my list into a vector, which doesn't preserve the ggplot correctly?

Comment: Have you changed the code? `flatten()` from `purrr` should only remove one level of the hierarchy. It should not make it into a vector. You had a list of lists before.

Comment: oh, yup! I had changed TypeLoop from `list()` to `c()`. I changed it back and your code worked perfectly. And it's a very clean solution, too - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `c` instead of `list` should ease the pain a bit.

```
TypeLoop <- function(fun) {
  all <- fun(c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"),"All")
  set <- fun("setosa","Setosa")
  vers <- fun("versicolor","Versicolor")
  virg <- fun("virginica","Verginica")
  return( c(all, set, vers, virg) )
}
```

The rest I cannot say for sure cause I did not try it in a knitr environment. But the next thing I would try is something like this. It seems to work in the console. You should be able to figure it out from here.

```
output <- function(x) {
  if ("gg" %in% class(x)) { 
    print(x)
  } else if ("knitr_kable" %in% class(x)) {
    cat(unlist(x), "\n")
  }
}
sapply(TypeLoop(PlotNTable), output)
```

Is that what you were looking for?